# How to implement a View which is always visible and fixed in MainActivity above all Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view, fragment

How to implement a View which is always visible and fixed in MainActivity above all Fragments?
I also need it to be like that also when the Fragment is replaced, not only when a Fragment is added.

Comment: What you are asking has very vague info. Also you should first study very basics of android Activity, how it displays views and how fragments can be used with Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation:vertical>

<!-- Your View above the fragment, f.e. an ImageView -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

<!-- Your fragment container -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

This should do the trick. Just replace the ImageView with the other view you want to place above the fragment.